# Location in request POST method

Tags: python, json

I need save location from Network [location is after add an element].

I tried to use:

```
    headers = {'charset': 'utf-8', 'Authorization': key}
    response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
    print(response.headers.get('Location'))
```

But in request, i had - None, how I can get this element?

Comment: try to `print(response.headers)` and you will see what headers do you have,

Comment: no i haven't this, i have all information but i hven't location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try to use `allow_redirects = False` ? it may help

```
response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
print(response.headers)
```